# The datanode stops abnormally during runtime. Is there a daemon to restart the datanode?

Tags: dolphindb

In a production environment, the datanode stops due to some reason. Is there a daemon which can restart the datanode and insure the business continuity?

Answer (score 0):

New features are supported in the latest version 1.30.11 and 1.20.20
Agent can automatically start the data node, and restart the data node when it shuts down unexpectedly. A new configuration item datanodeRestartInterval is added to controller.cfg.